# Copying data to slightly smaller disk

Tags: 20.04, dd, disk-image

I have a disk (32G) at `/dev/sda`, I want to clone that into a slightly smaller disk (30G) at `/dev/sdb`.

Both of them have just the one partition (`/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` respectively) currently not mounted on my system.

`/dev/sda` just has about 10G of actual data. So I would assume it's pretty easy to fit into 30G.

However, when I use `dd` with the following commands, it runs out of space (see error below) on `/dev/sdb`

1. `sudo dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K status=progress | gzip -c > disk-backup.gz`
2. `gunzip -c ./disk-backup.gz | sudo dd of=/dev/sdb1 conv=sync,noerror bs=64K status=progress`

How do I proceed for cloning this disk? And not that it should matter but these disks are bootable disks, containing linux OS

Edit: this is the output of `dd`

```
31974752256 bytes (32 GB, 30 GiB) copied, 257 s, 124 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/sdb1': No space left on device
488513+0 records in
488512+0 records out
32015122432 bytes (32 GB, 30 GiB) copied, 263.356 s, 122 MB/s
```

Record is off by one, and I don't know why bytes copied in the last line is different from the line before the error message

Edit: `/dev/sdb` goes into a deployed machine where it is the boot disk

Comment: Can't you just `conv=sparse` to truncate empty space?  `rsync` is pretty dope if you just want the files.  Also, are you saying that the results don't allow you to boot?  Can you please update your answer with how you boot `/dev/sdb` for testing?

Comment: The simplest way is: Use Clonezilla to clone to somewhere as backup, just in case the next step fails. Use gparted to make the partition smaller (like 29,8 GB). Use Clonezilla to clone the disk with option copy partition table. Voila.

Comment: `conv=sparse` does not work. `dd` still tries to copy over every byte I suppose. I checked online forums recommended using `zerofree`, maybe that `NULLs` unused bytes and then `dd` will not copy them over?